# The specified type 'CRM.DataModel.my_object' is not a known entity type

Tags: c#, dynamics-crm-2013

I have made a button in MS Dynamics CRM 2013 that runs some JavaScript, which runs a workflowactivity, that executes my .NET function.

I have tried returning just a string from the .NET code and all the above works.

However, when I now try to send my specific object through I get this error: **The specified type 'CRM.DataModel.my_object' is not a known entity type**

I have deducted that this is where my code crashes, at line 4:

```
1            try
2            {
3                //base.Context.ClearChanges();
4                my_object crmObject = base.Context.my_objectSet
5                    .SingleOrDefault(p => p.my_objectId.Value == objectId && p.statecode == my_objectState.Active);
6
7                if (crmobject != null)
8                {
9                    base.Logger.Trace("Object retrieved");
10                   result = this.CorvertFromCRM(crmObject);
11               }
12           }
```

Google gives my nothing usefull, and I dont know what the error means.
Any kind of help is appriciated. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

So it was figured out by a college of mine:

Go to Basis.WFActivities -> Properties -> **AssemblyInfo.cs**
At the bottom of this file paste the following:

```
[assembly: Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.ProxyTypesAssemblyAttribute()]
```

And thats it.

Answer (score 1):

1. Do you have actual my_object entity in CRM?
2. If you do, have you done early binding in your workflow solution?
3. Did you merge this early binded my_object with workflow dll?

Comment: Yes, I do the actual my_object entity in CRM (in real life all the 'objects' are named differently). I think I did the early binding, that is to say, that I think they are there (I am working on a huge pre-made solution). I conclude this because the CRM button and call to .NET worked with a more simple object (a string)

Comment: so check if dll with your generated early bind class(my_object) is actually merged with workflow dll you register. Do you use tools like ILMerge? btw, is it custom entity?

Comment: Thanks for your input @Nick

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I had to add to early bind class:

```
 [System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
 [Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Client.EntityLogicalNameAttribute("my_object")]
 [System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("CrmSvcUtil", "7.0.0000.3543")]
```

before

```
   public partial class my_object : Microsoft.Xrm.Sdk.Entity, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanging, System.ComponentModel.INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
```